# Using javascript & thyemleaf to manipulate a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, thymeleaf

I want to use in javascript an object from a list coming from the controller.
I'm using **Thymeleaf** with **Spring boot**.

The list name is `${collaborateurs}`.

The bellow code is working:

```js
<script th:inline="javascript">

      /*<![CDATA[*/
  
         var user = /*[[${collaborateurs[0].email}]]*/;
   alert(user);

       /*]]>*/
 
</script>
```

But I want to use some variable as index :

```js
<script th:inline="javascript">

      /*<![CDATA[*/
         var i = 1; // may be 0, 1, ....
         var user = /*[[${collaborateurs[i].email}]]*/;  // this code is not working
         alert(user);

       /*]]>*/
 
</script>
```

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: wait, what is your question again?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by trying to assign directly the list `${collaborateurs` to a javascript variable and access to my object directly from client side:

```js
<script th:inline="javascript">
  
      /*<![CDATA[*/
        var i = 1
        var users = /*[[${collaborateurs}]]*/;
 alert(users[i].email);
      /*]]>*/
 
</script>
```